# Extend djoser login method to get user roles

Tags: python, django, djoser

Djoser login api returns the user token, I also want to return user roles. How to implement such a case? Here is the method of logging on:

```
def login_user(request, user):
    token, _ = settings.TOKEN_MODEL.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if settings.CREATE_SESSION_ON_LOGIN:
        login(request, user)
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    return token
```

My goal is to achieve something like:

```
def login_user(request, user):
    token, new_user = settings.TOKEN_MODEL.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if not new_user:
        token_and_roles = {
            token: token,
            roles: [for group.lower() in User.objects.get(user).groups]
        }
        return token_and_roles
    if settings.CREATE_SESSION_ON_LOGIN:
        login(request, user)
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    return token
```

How to overwrite djoser api login method?

Comment: What's the issue with your approach?

Comment: I don't know the right way how to overwrite this method and prevent any side effect errors

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [djoser serializer settings doc](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers) - you need to write your own version of TokenSerializer and then set it in your settings:

```
DJOSER = {
    "SERIALIZERS": {"token": "myapp.serializers.MyTokenSerializer"},
}
```